# Recursive permutation of words in a sentence

Tags: python, recursion, permutation, sentence

I want to `recursively` get permutations of the words in sentence keeping adjacent words in packs of two, together from left to right.

So as an example if I consider `a, B, c, D` are 4 words and the main sentence has 5 occurrences of the 4 words as:

main sentence:    `a + B + c + a + D`

I would get four sentences as

```
c + a + B + c + a
a + B + c + a + D
a + B + c + a + B
B + c + a + B + c
```

which all have the same length as the main sentence, and it should be noted that the last word in the main sentence i.e. `D` only comes once and only at the end of the sentence after `a` because in the main sentence no word follows that.

Comment: You mention that you want a recursive solution, and then you mention a non-recursive solution. Which method are you using?

Comment: I will remove the second one - Let's solve it recursively :)

Comment: Is the same pair of adjacent words allowed to be repeated? If not, `c + a + B + c + a` should not be in the expected output.

Comment: @blhsing yes it is allowed, as long as the final sentence comes out the same length of the main sentence. so the above main sentence has only 4 acceptable results which are given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following recursive generator function:

```
def adjacent_combinations(sentence, target=None, length=0):
    if not target:
        for target in set(sentence):
            for combination in adjacent_combinations(sentence, target, 1):
                yield combination
    elif length == len(sentence):
        yield [target]
    else:
        for a, b in set(zip(sentence, sentence[1:])):
            if a == target:
                for combination in adjacent_combinations(sentence, b, length + 1):
                    yield [a] + combination
```

so that:

```
list(adjacent_combinations(['a', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'D']))
```

would return:

```
[['B', 'c', 'a', 'B', 'c'],
 ['c', 'a', 'B', 'c', 'a'],
 ['a', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'B'],
 ['a', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'D']]
```

Comment: gives error that maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison, also yield from does not work in python <3.3

Comment: Oops I did make a typo. I've also updated my answer not to use `yield from`. Please try again now.

Comment: there is a corner case with your code, for the sentence 'a' + 'b' prints empty and for sentence 'a' + 'a' + 'a' prints 8 times 'a' + 'a' + 'a'

Comment: I see. Fixed then. Please try again now.

Comment: still for sentence 'a' + 'a' + 'a' prints 4 times 'a' + 'a' + 'a'

Comment: I see. Fixed then. Please try again now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator with recursion:

```
s = ['a', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'D']
def combinations(d, _c = []):
  if len(_c) == len(d)+1:
     yield _c
  else:
     for i in d:
       if not _c or any(s[c] == _c[-1] and s[c+1] == i for c in range(len(s)-1)):
          for k in combinations(d, _c+[i]):
            yield k

print('\n'.join(' + '.join(i) for i in combinations(set(s))))
```

Output:

```
a + B + c + a + B
a + B + c + a + D
B + c + a + B + c
c + a + B + c + a
```

Comment: smart one, but output is not correct, if you note to what I wrote above, only the words that are next to each other from left to right can be together, e.g. in your output 'c','a' is not allowed since in s 'c' is never followed by 'a', and also the output should be the same length as the main sentence, i.e. 4 in your s

Comment: @Soyol In every sequence of your desired output, the number of letters is five. Also, 'c' is followed by 'a' in `B + c + a + B + c` as posted in your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, true I have given two words, but the reference is the main sentence which is `a + B + c + a + D` and we want to get permutation of this sentence and honor the fact that words which are next to each other from left to right remain next to each other and the final permutation ends up having same length as the reference sentence

Comment: @Soyol Please see my recent edit. Each is now compared to `['a', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'D']`.

Comment: now you have extra outputs, for instance 'a' 'a' being together is not allowed since in the main sentence never to 'a' are next to each other. Also 'a' 'c' is not allowed since in the main sentence 'c' 'a' is happening only. As I mentioned the direction of left to right for adjacency should be followed, i.e. 'c' 'a' is allowed in permutations but 'a' 'c' is not.

Comment: @Soyol Thank you for clarifying. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: there is an issue with this approach which I now noticed and it's that the syntax is not supported in python<3.3 !

Comment: @Soyol Do you mean the original `yield from` statement? I have added a generic `yield`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Using `[]` as a default value for parameter `_c` makes subsequent calls to `combinations` incorrect. Try calling `combinations` again with a different input after calling it to see what I mean.

Comment: there is a corner case with this code as well:
'a' + 'b' comes out empty
'a' + 'a' + 'a' + 'a' comes out 'a' + 'a'